# How to make CSS SVG files close together using Flex

Tags: html, css

This is my first post on here as it seems to be quite a weird problem.

I am very new to HTML and CSS but I seemed to have learnt the majority of it in a couple of days.
There is one thing which is very confusing to me regarding flex. It has been very simple when dealing with other elements, like the links in the Navigation at the top of the page. However when I have put flex on the Social Media SVG icons, they have this weird spacing between them.

[Here is me hovering my mouse over the gaps when in F12 picker mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhqtp.png)

The spacing isnt padding or margins or anything like that. All I have done is set the container they are in to have display:flex; and that is it. Any help will be appriciated!

[The website I am building with the problem area circled in red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBcla.png)

Side note: Sorry most of the site is blurred, it contains potentially sensitive information about a small organisation I wouldn't like to be shared :(

Here is the CSS Code:

```
.footer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.social-icons ul {
  display: flex;
}

.social-icons img {
  width: 5em;
}
```

Here is the questionable HTML:

```
<footer id="footer" class="padding-block-big text-primary-heading bg-main fw-regular fs-small">
  <div class="footer">
    <div class="social-icons">
      <h3 class="fs-regular">
        Follow Us:
      </h3>
      <ul role="list" aria-label="Social Media Links">
        <li><a aria-label="Facebook" href=""><img src="Images\Facebook.svg" alt="Facebook"></a></li>
        <li><a aria-label="Twitter" href=""><img src="Images\Twitter.svg" alt="Twitter"></a></li>
        <li><a aria-label="Instagram" href=""><img src="Images\Instagram.svg" alt="Instagram"></a></li>
        <li><a aria-label="YouTube" href=""><img src="Images\Youtube.svg" alt="Youtube"></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: @AlonEitan The SVG's are square and dont contain any extra information. They are not standard images. I have updated my post with the code. I though it was a stupid issue, hence why I didnt think the code would be needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `flex` on a `ul` tag which has its own styles (like padding and list-style), so I reset those.

```css
.footer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.social-icons ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.social-icons img {
  width: 5em;
}
```

```html
<footer id="footer" class="padding-block-big text-primary-heading bg-main fw-regular fs-small">
  <div class="footer">
    <div class="social-icons">
      <h3 class="fs-regular">
        Follow Us:
      </h3>
      <ul role="list" aria-label="Social Media Links">
        <li>
          <a aria-label="Facebook" href=""><img src="Images\Facebook.svg" alt="Facebook"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a aria-label="Twitter" href=""><img src="Images\Twitter.svg" alt="Twitter"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a aria-label="Instagram" href=""><img src="Images\Instagram.svg" alt="Instagram"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a aria-label="YouTube" href=""><img src="Images\Youtube.svg" alt="Youtube"></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```